# OS Error 22 when I try to deploy YOLOv8 on GPU

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, torch, oserror, yolov8

I copy and paste the code from ultralytics website:

```
import torch
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('yolov8n.yaml')  # build a new model from YAML
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)
model = YOLO('yolov8n.yaml').load('yolov8n.pt') 
model.train(data='coco128.yaml', epochs=100, imgsz=640)  # Train the model
```

This is what I am using:Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.90  Python-3.8.2 torch-1.12.0+cu113 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, 12288MiB)
However, I keep receiving this error:

```
train: Scanning E:\python_learning\datasets\coco128\labels\train2017.cache... 126 images, 2 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|██████████| 128/128 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 262, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 232, in _get_code_from_file
    with io.open_code(fname) as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\python_learning\\venv\\<input>'
```

I have been stuck on this for days, any help would be really appreciated.
BTW, I train this model on my CPU perfectly, it took me 3 hours to train but it works. So I assume it might be a problem involve with GPU setting or environment pathway or else.